# Do we only need Choice for higher order-statements (Zorn’s lemma as example)?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

In [this earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3185192/360475), I asked why the axiom of choice, which is an axiom in *set theory*, is used in areas that are not set theory, such as group theory. The answer was that, whenever choice is used, it is used to prove something about the *set of models* of group theory, and hence is a statement about sets rather than about groups.

Now I’m trying to understand this for Zorn’s lemma specifically. 
Zorn’s lemma says:

> **Zorn’s Lemma** — Suppose a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain in $P$ has an upper bound in $P$. Then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

The axiom of choice is used in the proof of Zorn’s lemma. This at first sight confused me, since Zorn’s lemma seems like a theorem about partial orders, not about sets in general. But then I realized that it is a second-order statement, rather than first order, since it is about *subsets* of $P$. I don’t fully understand the proof of Zorn’s lemma, since I’m somewhat confused still by the axiom of choice, so let me ask a question to clarify:

> **Question 1**. Is it true that the proof of Zorn’s lemma uses the axiom of choice *on totally ordered subsets* of $P$, rather than on $P$ itself?

This gives me the more general conjecture:

> **Question 2**. Is it true that whenever we have a first-order statement about a structure (such as posets), we *never* need the axiom of choice to prove it, but if the statement is higher-order, we *may* need it?

Note that (in the context of partial orders) I’m talking about first-order statements within the theory of partial orders, not e.g. first-order statements about the set of models of the theory of partial orders, or e.g. about the category of posets.

Comment: What does the question even mean? Higher order statements? Extend your language to be multisorted and everything becomes first-order.

Comment: The existence of a maximal element is a first-order statement. Yes, the condition on upper bounds is not first-order in the language of orders, but it is not what we want to prove anyway.

Comment: It's a bit late, so I won't be pinging anyone, but I'd just like to reply to the above comments that an implication between a second order property and a first order one is itself a second order statement, so I think the question is meaningful (if a bit fuzzy).

Answer (score 3):

There is certainly a strong sense in which the answer to your question is **yes**: namely, model-existence - and hence semantic entailment in general - doesn't depend on choice (unless our language is quite weird, namely non-well-orderable).

The completeness theorem in its full glory is indeed not provable in ZF alone, but this is only because complicated languages are permitted. As long as the language of the theory in question is well-orderable (and it's hard to come up with a natural example which consistently isn't), the Henkin construction goes through without choice. Since choice doesn't affect syntactic consistency (the latter being all about finite sequences), this means that as long as the language in question is well-orderable we'll never need choice to tell whether a given semantic entailment holds.

For example, if ZFC proves that every group satisfies some first-order sentence $\varphi$, then so does ZF - the point being that the language $\langle e,*,{}^{-1}\rangle$ of groups is well-orderable (indeed, finite).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand your answer, as I find it a bit hard to connect to my question 2. To start, what do you mean by a "non-well-orderable language"? Secondly, what does model existence not depending on choice have to do with first-order statements not needing choice to prove them?

Comment: @user56834 Re: your first question, remember that a first-order language is just a set of symbols of appropriate type. If choice fails, there are some sets which are non-well-orderable; well, this leads to sets of symbols which are non-well-orderable. For example, consider the language consisting of an $n$-ary function symbol for each $n$-ary function on $\mathbb{R}$ (this language shows up in nonstandard analysis, for example). This set of symbols is incredibly huge; it has size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. So if the powerset of the reals isn't well-orderable, neither is this language. (cont'd)

Comment: @user56834 Re: your first question, remember that a first-order language is just a set of symbols of appropriate type. If choice fails, there are some sets which are non-well-orderable; well, this leads to sets of symbols which are non-well-orderable. For example, consider the language consisting of an $n$-ary function symbol for each $n$-ary function on $\mathbb{R}$ (this language shows up in nonstandard analysis, for example). This set of symbols is incredibly huge; it has size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. So if the powerset of the reals isn't well-orderable, neither is this language. (cont'd)

Comment: Of course such languages actually occur only very rarely in practice; basically every first-order language you actually use is even *finite*! But they do crop up from time to time. Re: your second question, model existence is "dual" to entailment: "$T$ entails $\varphi$" is equivalent to "There is no model of $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$." Showing that choice plays no role in model existence arguments of a certain kind also shows that it plays no role in semantic entailment arguments of that same kind.

Comment: Regarding your final point, don't you mean that choice playing no role in model existence is equivalent to choice playing no role in **provability** (rather than entailment, as you said)? My question was about provability.

Comment: @user56834 No, I don't. Choice playing no role in provability is trivial: "$T\vdash\varphi$" holds iff there is a finite sequence of formulas satisfying a certain simple property, and Choice has no bearing on finite objects. Things only get potentially interesting when we talk about entailment, since the entailment/provability equivalence requires a bit of choice once we leave the realm of well-ordered languages. Basically, the point is that we rarely phrase things as "$T\vdash\varphi$" and more commonly say "Every model of $T$ satisfies $\varphi$" (e.g. "Every group is ----").

Comment: Indeed that's sort of the whole point of my second paragraph: a priori we know that choice is irrelevant for proofs from theories in a given language, and as long as our language is well-orderable we can go further and say that choice is irrelevant for *entailments* of theories in that language. So while this steps a it outside pure provability, the point is that really all that's going on is confirming that provability means what it should in these cases.